# Error on Rake Test on Yield & Provide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a bit new on Ruby on Rails and currently following  Michael Hartl’s tutorial on Rails.

As I was testing using 'Guard', it says,

```html
After running bundle exec rake test below are the results:

1) Failure:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home [c:/Usrs/Code Box/workspace/feed/test/static_pages_controller_test.rb:7]:
<Home | Ruby on Rails Sample App> expected but was <Feed>..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.
  
  3 runs, 6 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 sips.
```

I want the title on each page to change dynamically so here's my application view,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= yield(:title) %> | Ruby on Rails Sample App</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here's the Home view as stated on the error message,

```html
<% provide(:title, "Home") %>
<h1>Lipsum</h1>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, distinctio! Quidem eaque labore eos ipsam a aliquam, eius. Distinctio quo reprehenderit nostrum commodi quod assumenda consequatur officia, placeat sit fugit.
</p>
```

Lastly, here's the test controller,

```html
class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get home" do
    get :home
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Home | Ruby on Rails Sample App"
  end
```

Comment: Which line in the test is causing the error? Best to include the full error trace.

Comment: Line 7 - which is this - assert_select "title", "Home | Ruby on Rails Sample App"

Answer (score 0):

Your code in your view is "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App", but your test is expecting "Ruby on Rails Sample App". Is that a typo here or the problem?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry a typo. Still, the title doesn't show it just says the application name.

Answer (score 0):

"Ah ha!" moment. It seems I am editing the wrong Application.html.erb file from another folder which causes the error because the declaration on the original Application.html.erb does not have 'Yield' on the title.

Solved. Thanks!